# Transpose multiple occurrences

Tags: excel-formula, transpose

**EDIT: I have revived the source data source to remove the ambiguity of my last screen shots**

I am trying to transpose spreadsheet data where there are many rows where the customer name may be duplicated but each row contains a different product.

For instance
[revised original data source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y45Nc.png)

to

[revised proposed data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLYDV.png)

I would like to do it with formulae if possible as I struggle with VB

Thank you for any help

Comment: Hmm I could knock up an INDEX for that but surely it's possible for you to have 2 customers with identically spelled names within that list?

Comment: Indeed, but the customer ID would be unique to each customer so say another John Smith may be JS502

Comment: Erm Okay but in the example, you grouped the unique customer ID's is taht just a mistake then?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry. The ID's show that it is the same client but the report has separate rows for each unique product

Comment: cool, give me 20-30 minutes and I'll knock up the INDEX after this business call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realise this is a huge answer, apologies but I wanted to be clear. If you need anything from me, drop me a comment and I'll help out.

Here's the output from my formula:
[image]

**EDITED ANSWER - Named ranges used for ease of understanding:**

[image][image][image]

These are just an example of a few of the named ranges I have used, you can reference the ranges directly or name them yourself (simplest way is to highlight the data then put the name in the drop down next to the formula bar [top left])

Be wary that as we will be using Array formulas for AccNum and AccType, you will not want to select the entire column and instead opt for either the exact data length or overshoot it by 100 or so. Large array formulas tend to slow down calculation and will calculate every cell individually regardless of it being empty.

***First formula***

`=IF(COUNTIF(D2:D11,">""")>0,CONCATENATE("Account Number ",LEFT((COLUMN(A:A)+1)/2,1)),"")`

This formula is identical to the one in the original answer apart form the adjusted heading title.

`=IF(Condition,True,False)` - There are so many uses for the `IF` logic, it is the best formula in Excel in my opinion. I have used to IF with `COUNTIF` to check whether there is more than 0 cells that are more than BLANK (or `""`). This is just a trick around using `ISBLANK()` or other blank identifiers that get confused when formula is present.

If the result is TRUE, I use `CONCATENATE(Text1,Text2,etc.)` to build a text string for the column header. `ROW(1:1)` or `COLUMN(A:A)` is commonly used to initiate an automatically increasing integer for formulas to use based on whether the count increase is required horizontally or vertically. I add 1 to this increasing integer and divide it by 2 so that the increase for each column is 0.5 (1 > 1.5 > 2 > 2.5) I then use `LEFT` formula to just take the first digit to the left of this decimal answer so the number increases only once every 2 columns.

If the result is FALSE then leave the cell blank `,"")`. Standard stuff here, no explanation needed.

***Second Formula***

`=CONCATENATE(INDEX(Forename,MATCH(Sheet4!$A2,Reference,0)))`
`=CONCATENATE(INDEX(Surname,MATCH(Sheet4!$A2,Reference,0)))`

`CONCATENATE` has only been used here to force blank cells to remain blank when pulled by `INDEX`. `INDEX` will read blank cells as values and therefore `0`'s whereas `CONCATENATE` will read them as text and therefore `""`.

`INDEX(Range,Row,Column)`: This is a lookup formula that is much more advanced than `VLOOKUP` or `HLOOKUP` and not limited in the way that they are.

The range i have used is the expected output range - `Forename` or `Surname`

The row is then calculated using `MATCH(Criteria,Range,Match Type)`. Match will look through a range and return the position as an integer where a match occurs. For this I have set the criteria to the unique reference number in column A for that row, the range to the named range `Reference` and the match type as 0 (1 Less than, 0 Exact Match, -1 Greater than).

I did not define a column number for INDEX as it defaults to the first column and I am only giving it one column of data to output from anyway.

***Third Formula***

Remember these need to be entered as an array (when in the formula bar hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

`=IFERROR(INDEX(AccNum,SMALL(IF(Reference=Sheet4!$A2,ROW(Reference)-ROW(INDEX(Reference,1,1))+1),ROUNDDOWN((COLUMN(A:A)+1)/2,0))),"")`

`=IFERROR(INDEX(AccType,SMALL(IF(Reference=Sheet4!$A2,ROW(Reference)-ROW(INDEX(Reference,1,1))+1),ROUNDDOWN((COLUMN(B:B)+1)/2,0))),"")`

As you can see, one of these is used for `AccNum` and the other for `AccType`.

`IFERROR(Value)`: The reason that this has been used is that we are not expecting the formula to always return something. When the formula cannot return something or SMALL has run out of matches to go through then an error will occur (usually #VALUE or #NUM!) so i use `,"")` to force a blank result instead (again standard stuff).

I have already explained the INDEX formula above so let's just dive in to how I have worked out the rows that match what we are looking for:

`SMALL(IF(Reference=Sheet4!$A2,ROW(Reference)-ROW(INDEX(Reference,1,1))+1),ROUNDDOWN((COLUMN(B:B)+1)/2,0))`

The IF statement here is fairly self explanatory but as we have used it as an array formula, it will perform `=Sheet4!$A2` which is the unique reference on every cell in the named range `Reference` individually. In your mock data this returns a result of: `{FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE}` for the first entry (I included titles in the range, hence the initial FALSE). `IF` will do my row calculation* for every true but leave the `FALSE`s as they are.

This leaves a result of {FALSE;2;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE} that `SMALL(array,k)` will use. `SMALL` will only work on numeric values and will display the 'k'th result. Again the column trick has been used but to cover more ground, I used another method: `ROUNDDOWN(Number,digits)` as opposed to using `LEFT()` Digits here means decimal places so I used 0 to round down to a whole integer for the same result. As this copies across the columns like so: `1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3`, `SMALL` will alternatively (as the formulas alternate) grab the 1st smallest AccNum then the 1st Smallest AccType before grabbing the 2nd AccNum and Acctype and so forth.

*(Row number of the match minus the first row number of the range then plus 1, again fairly common as a foolproof way to always get the correct row regardless of where the data starts; actually as your data starts on row 1 we could just do `ROW(Reference)` but I left it as is incase you had data in a different format)

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER - Same logic as above**

**Here's your solution in 3 parts**

***Part 1*** being a trick for the auto completion of the titles so that they will hide when not used (in case you will just copay and paste values the whole lot to speed up use again).

[image]
`=IF(COUNTIF(C2:C11,">""")>0,CONCATENATE("Product ",LEFT((COLUMN(A:A)+1)/2,1)),"")` in C

`=IF(COUNTIF(D2:D11,">""")>0,CONCATENATE("Prod code ",LEFT((COLUMN(B:B)+1)/2,1)),"")` in D

Highlight both of the cells and drag across to stagger the outputs `"Product "` and `"Prod code "`

***Part 2*** would be inputting the unique IDs to the new sheet, I would suggest copying your entire column A across to a new sheet and using `DATA > REMOVE DUPLICATES > Continue with current selection` to trim out the multiple occurrences of unique IDs.

In column B use `=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$7,MATCH(Sheet4!$A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$7,0))` to get the names pulled across.

***Part 3*, the INDEX**
[image]
[image]

Once again, we are doing a staggered input here before copying the formula across the page to cover the entirety of the data.

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$C$1:$D$11,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$11=Sheet4!$A2,ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$11)-ROW(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$11,1,1))+1),ROUNDDOWN((COLUMN(A:A)+1)/2,0)),1),"")` in C

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$C$1:$D$11,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$11=Sheet4!$A2,ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$11)-ROW(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$11,1,1))+1),ROUNDDOWN((COLUMN(B:B)+1)/2,0)),2),"")` in D

The formulas of Part 3 will need to be entered as an array (when in the formula bar hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) . This will need to be done before copying the formulas across.

These formulas can now be dragged / copied in all directions and will feed off of the unique ID in column A.

*My Answer is already rather long so I haven't gone on to break the formula down. If you have any trouble understanding how this works, let me know and I will be happy to write up a quick guide, breaking it down chunk by chunk for you.*

Comment: Hi, I am sorry that I wasn't clear in my original post (which I have no revised). If it's not too much trouble would you mind reviewing the new screenshots I have attached and let me know if it is far off from your response?

Comment: @Patrick It is very similar. I have meetings all day today, but when I get a chance I will break the formula down to help you to understand how it works and show you how it fits the new scope.

Comment: @Patrick Updated the answer to fit the new data, give me a shout if you need any help understanding the essay I wrote haha. If this gets the job done, please remember to mark my answer as accepted (the tick to the left) thanks.

Comment: Thank you! Umm have you got a workbook I could download to work through?....I regret telling my boss 'that I know a bit about excel'!

Comment: Unfortunately not, I use internet searches to find breakdown's of formulas then put them to practice until I understand how they work and memorise them. I have never worked from text books or tutorial sites so unable to help there but I like how users on exceljet.net break down formula so I keep an eye out for those when I do searches. Also searching here on SO with keywords relating to what you are looking for often finds a similar situation that you can use for reference.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I just meant if I could view your .xls file I could understand it better...

Comment: Oh I get you now. Alas, I work for a top ten Bank. External data transfer is a no-go here, all I can do is provide the screenshots and explanation.

Comment: @Patrick I have used the exact same data though, and if you follow the formulas like this you will have the exact same end result to study: A1:C1 are just typed headings (C&P). D1 has part 1 of formula 1 in and E1 has part 2 of formula 1 though you don't need this formula you can manually type out the numbers etc. both of these are highlighted then copied across a fair distance of the row.

Comment: Formula 2 part 1 is in B2 and part 2 in C2

Comment: Formula 3 part 1 is in D2 and part 2 is in E2 (array formula so Ctrl Shift Enter) both parts highlighted first then this can be dragged down and across to cover all data

Comment: Column A was copying the column D from your data and doing the DATA > REMOVE duplicates thing that I mentioned in the original answer

Comment: I have managed to get this working thank you. I have been trying to include a couple of additional columns ('fund choice' and 'active'), however when I drag the formula across from Account type 1 it doesn't seem to pull through all the funds and active Y/N's from the source sheet. I have been reading through your explanation of the formula with part 3 but haven't found my solution yet

Comment: Good to hear. The formula is already searching for the unique id's and amalgamating them so the INDEX formula will only need the target (first) named range changed to the column 'fund choice' and 'active'. With the addition of the extra 2 columns: `(COLUMN(B:B)+3)/4,0)`. Accept this as an answer when you have it working please, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have it working! My rep is below 15, so I can't tick the answer above but I appreciate your assistance on this

Comment: @Patrick YES! Good luck with the rest of your excel journey... ♥